# Windows Vista stops VirtualBox Graphics Adapter (WDDM) with error code 43

Tags: virtualbox, drivers, windows-vista, hardware-acceleration, guest-additions

I have a Windows Vista virtual machine which I'd like to enable 3D Acceleration on. If I install VirtualBox Guest Additions it successfully installs the driver and reboots the VM, however I don't get access to Aero for example, and if I open `devmgmt.msc` I get the following error on the display adapter:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

Click 'Check for solutions' to send data about this device to Microsoft and to see if there is a solution available.
```

If I click `Update Driver Software...` the driver will be reverted to the Standard VGA one which does not support 3D Acceleration.

How can I fix the issue and make the driver start correctly?

Comment: My Vista VM here permits setting 3D Acceleration and it is set ON.  VMware not VBOX.  .... Do you have another Windows VM with 3D ON?  I have 3D set ON for my Windows 7 VM as well.

Comment: Yeah, Windows 10 has 3D Acceleration turned on, and it works.

Comment: Maybe try building a new, test Vista machine and see if 3D works that way. You might need to download and install SP2 after the test install.